# Wordpress Theme Customization

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project in which I need to have the wordpress theme Spark Child Theme along with functionality of bootstrap header. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try your code if faces problum then post the code you will get the solution

Comment: I am able to use Bootstrap separately, and the wordpress theme separately too, but could not figure out how to integrate both of them.

Comment: have  you include the files in  header.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are using separate files  for change   css then you need to include the  files in you header.php  and other things accordingly  you can customize

Answer (score 1):

You need to enqueue the bootstrap CSS and JS file in function.php file.

Also if you need to change the CSS from the separate file so you need to enqueue the CSS file as well.

you can enqueue the file using below code:

```
    function pwwp_enqueue_my_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap javascript goodness
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );


        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pwwp_enqueue_my_scripts');
```

Style.css is the custom/default stylesheet for WordPress.

Answer (score -1):

To use a header, wrap your heading in a `<div>` with a class of `.page-header` as shown below:

```html
<div class = "page-header">
   
   <h1>
      Example page header 
      <small>Subtext for header</small>
   </h1>
   
</div>

<p>This is a sample text.This is a sample text.This is a sample text. This is a sample text.</p>
```

Wordpress Acool theme may be suitable for your project. You can preview this theme at https://www.coothemes.com/